# How to repeat rdlc full page

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm using VS 2013, VB.Net, and web forms.  I have an rdlc file that has a table with dynamic content.  Above the table there are some text boxes, some of the text boxes have static content, but some have dynamic content as well.

[image: red arrows - dynamic outside of table, green arrow - table]

*red arrows - dynamic outside of table, green arrow - table*

I am feeding this report an `IEnumerable(of T)`(t is a custom object).  My issue is that on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th.... etc. pages, the boxes that are not in the table do not render.

I have tried putting the boxes above the table into a report header, which does make them repeat.  The problem with this is that the dynamic content from the first report is shown on every page.

Is there a setting I'm missing that will make the entire page render for each report, or is my best option now to move all the text boxes into the table?

A little background, this report has existed for years as it stands, but the client has only been able to run one at a time.  The new requirement is to generate all the reports that meet a certain condition, one report per page.  So staying as close to the original look as possible is critical.  I'm hoping to avoid putting the other boxes in a table so as to not add the dark border around them.

*Edit* I just found a setting "repeat with".  This setting is located by highligting an individual text box, then going to the properties menu.  When I select "Repeat with `table1`", the text boxes are repeated, but they only show the value from the first object.

The report's data source is set up to mirror the custom object below.  A collection of these objects is put into an IEnumerable like this:

```
Dim pendingPerformanceReviewReports As IEnumerable(Of PerformanceReviewReportScheme)
```

and then send it to the rdlc.

Custom object constructor:

```
Public Class PerformanceReviewReportScheme
    Public Property ConfNumber As String
    Public Property Appointment As String
    Public Property PerformancePlanStatus As String
    Public Property ProcessLevel As String
    Public Property Department As String
    Public Property PositionCode As String
    Public Property EmployeesName As String
    Public Property EmployeeID As Integer?
    Public Property PositionCodeDescriptionLevel As String
    Public Property CurrentPayRate As String
    Public Property ProposedPayRate As String
    Public Property ProposedEffectiveDate As String
    Public Property NextReviewDate As String
    Public Property PerformanceRating As String
    Public Property BasePayIncreaseDollars As String
    Public Property BasePayIncreasePercentage As String
    Public Property LumpSumBonusDollars As String
    Public Property LumpSumBonusPercentage As String
    Public Property RequestedBy As String
    Public Property RequestedOn As String
End Class
```

Comment: Does each item in your `IEnumerable (of T)` represent a page in the report?

Comment: Yes, each object should be it's own page

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a good example, but there should be a data list control or something similar you can put on your report, the table will be inside of that as well as the fields above the table. The data source for that will be your `IEnumerable (Of T)`, so basically everything inside of that list will be rendered for each item in your collection. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BrianBall I've added a list to the report, and placed my table and other boxes inside the list.  But I receive an error: "The tablix ‘table1’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members."  I tried adding a list with only the top boxes, which did work in getting the proper values to repeat, but it repeats all the top portions, and then all the bottom portions.

Comment: You may need to change how you are referencing your values from the tablix. I don't know what your object structure looks like (is it a collection that contains another collection?) Try adding a blank tablix to the list and adding one or two fields values in there and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting all my fields in the table and adding them to the existing group.  You are able to select individual cells and remove their borders.

While this solution does work, it is not ideal. I do not have the flexibility that comes with being able to place text boxes on a blank sheet wherever I please.